# SQL select count and data multiple numbers

Tags: sql, dbf

I'm a student and for a scripting I need to select some data, but I can't figure it out.

I have a dbf with

```
BAS      13-01-2016 13:32
BAS      13-01-2016 13:33
BAS      13-01-2016 13:36
BAS      12-01-2016 13:37
TECH     13-01-2016 13:38
TECH     13-01-2016 13:45
```

I want to make a selection of today with the last time and also the count of the day

The result must be:

```
BAS     13-01-2016 13:33    3
TECH    13-01-2016 13:45    2
```

How can I do this? I know it's not a difficult question but I just can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Use `agregate` functions to solve your task. For example:

```
SELECT T.col1,
       COUNT(*) AS cnt,
       MAX(date) AS max_date
FROM Table AS T
WHERE T.date >= DATE()
GROUP BY col1
```

`Col1` is a table column that contains values like `'BAS', 'TECH'` and others.